# How to loop inside vuejs template without breaking html code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

so im trying to loop inside a table. I have encountered a problem is that

```
<tr v-for="( block , index ) in listRenderBlock" :key="index">
    <div v-for="( section , i ) in block.sections" :key=" i ">
        <td> 
           <p>
              {{ block.name }}
           </p>
        </td>
        <td>
           <p>
              {{ section.name }}
           </p>
        </td>
    </div>
</tr>
```

So if im trying to loop like this the div will break the table's code.
I know that if in react i can do sth like

```
blocks.sections.map(value => ....)
```

But that doesnt seems to work in vuejs too.
Any suggestions guys? All comments are appreciated, and thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to loop without using wrappers, use a `<template>`:

```
<tr v-for="( block , index ) in listRenderBlock" :key="index">
  <template v-for="(section , i ) in block.sections">
    <td :key="`b_${index}_${i}`"> 
      <p>
        {{ block.name }}
      </p>
    </td>
    <td :key="`s_${index}_${i}`">
      <p>
        {{ section.name }}
      </p>
    </td>
  </template>
</tr>
```

Note: `<div>`'s are invalid children of `<tr>`.

See it working:

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.config.devtools = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    listRenderBlock: [{
      name: 'B-1',
      sections: [
        { name: 'S-1' },
        { name: 'S-2' }
      ]
    }, {
      name: 'B-2',
      sections: [
        { name: 'S-1' },
        { name: 'S-2' }
      ]
    }]
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<table id="app">
  <tr v-for="(block, index) in listRenderBlock" :key="index">
    <template v-for="(section, i) in block.sections">
      <td :key="`b_${index}_${i}`"> 
         <p v-text="block.name" />
      </td>
      <td :key="`s_${index}_${i}`">
         <p v-text="section.name" />
      </td>
    </template>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Another note: `<template>`'s can't be `:key`-ed, as they don't end up being DOM elements. So you have to come up with your own `:key`-ing system, applied to the actual DOM elements. In your case, I made keys out of `index` + `i`, prefixed by either `b` for block `<td>`'s or `s` for section `<td>`'s. It doesn't really matter how the keys look like, as long as they're unique. (They are not displayed anywhere, they're just used by Vue to update the DOM elements when your model/data changes).